# Disabling full row select in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows

Im not sure if I am using the correct terminology, but when I am clicking on a particular file in a folder, the other files above the one I am selecting also open. When clicking on my desired file, the files above it are selected as well. Im not quite sure what I did, but does anyone know how to turn this off? What is this function called?

--- UPDATED QUESTION ---

One of my clients is remoting in to her work machine using Team Viewer. She noticed that whenever she would try to open a certain folder, said problem would occur. As soon as she quit TeamViewer, I tried to replicate the problem, and nothing happened. Everything worked as it should. Could this possibly be an issue with her remote machine, or TeamViewer itself? I'm not really sure. Im trying to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Your description sounds like the default behaviour for holding down the shift key and selecting a file, is it possible you have accidentally enabled 'Sticky Keys'? You can check this from the Ease of Access Center in the Control Panel.

Comment: Sticky Keys is turned off, so I dont think that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was posted after OP replied to the other answer, providing crucial information. Apparently, their client uses a remote desktop solution (In this case TeamViewer) to take over a computer.

What your client is experiencing is called a stuck key.

Basically when your session disconnects while the shift was pressed, windows will continue to think this key is pressed. A reboot will likely help, but a much simpler fix is to simply press both shift keys once.

Pressing the keys is simply, press, then release. Don't press any other key, nor press both shifts at the same time.

The same usually happens with the CTRL and ALT as well. Typing suddenly can open menus or perform actions, etc.

Comment: I've updated the question and removed my comment. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A reboot of the remote machine fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a (known) glitch on Windows 7 and 8. I found a cnet article talking about this and a fix designed by Ramesh Srinivasan.

Source: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/a-fix-for-the-multifile-selection-glitch-in-windows-7-and-8/

A brief sum up of it:

- Create a restore point (in case anything weird happens...)
- Open RegEdit

  - Export this key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Classes \ Local Settings \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Shell \ Bags`
  - Export this key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Classes \ Local Settings \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Shell \ BagMRU`
  - Now delete both of them (left pane)
- Apply this w7-fullrowsel.zip reg file (in a zip with undo)

Or copy and paste it if you don't trust the zip:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Disable Full Row Select feature in Windows 7
;Created by Ramesh Srinivasan
;http://www.winhelponline.com/Blog
;Created on 19 Feb 2010

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"FullRowSelect"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"KnownFolderDerivedFolderType"="{57807898-8C4F-4462-BB63-71042380B109}"
"SniffedFolderType"="Generic"

;Generic - Folder Template

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"Rev"=dword:00000000
"FFlags"=dword:43000001
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001


;Documents - Folder Template

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}]
"Rev"=dword:00000000
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
"FFlags"=dword:43000001


;Music - Folder Template

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}]
"Rev"=dword:00000000
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
"FFlags"=dword:43000001


;Pictures - Folder Template

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}]
"Rev"=dword:00000000
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
"FFlags"=dword:43000001


;Videos - Folder Template

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}]
"Rev"=dword:00000000
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
"FFlags"=dword:43000001
```

Now, you can either do a full restart (cleanest solution) or open up `taskmgr` and right click kill `explorer.exe`

---

The solution is a bit geared towards fixing the multi-file selection on row change, but may eliminate that problem as well.

Comment: @AnthonySims that is very crucial information that you had left out. I'll post an answer now that I know this.

Comment: @LPChip Yeah, very crucial to have known...